# Having ng-model and ng-value set for the single input field

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs

**HTML CODE**

```
<div>
    <label for="date">Update Time:</label>
    <input id="date"  ng-model="formData.Updt_Time" ng-value="ts">
</div>
```

Here i am trying to assign ng-model and ng-value to the input field since i m the value(ng-value="ts") this ***ts*** would be coming from my controller, and i will have to save the data to formData. On form submit i will be inserting all the values in the set formData to my mySQL.

**CONTROLLER CODE**

```
clientApp.controller('formCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.statuses = ["Active", "Inactive"];
    $scope.cluster = ["East Coast","West Coast","PayPal"]
    // Update Date 
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var yr=currentTime.getFullYear()
    var mnth=currentTime.getMonth()
    var dt=currentTime.getDate()
        if (mnth < 10) {
        mnth = "0" + mnth
        }
        if (dt < 10) {
        dt = "0" + dt
        }

    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()

    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds
    }
    $scope.ts = yr + "-" +mnth+ "-" + dt + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " ";
    //when submit button is clicked 
    $scope.submit = function() {
           alert("Submit Clicked");
           $http.post('/clientPost', $scope.formData).success(function(response) {
                console.log('Data posted successfully');
            })

                    .error(function(data){
                            console.log("There is an error");
                            console.log('Error: ' + data);
                    });
    };
});
```

How ever the ng-model and ng-value doesn't seem to work together. Is there a workaround.

Comment: set input model reference to $scope, like <input id="date"  ng-model="ts">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of I have a few recommendations:

- You should start using the 'controller as' notation in Angular, as it is more readable and does not clutter up the $scope. (Check out John Papa's style guide for writing better Angular code: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)
- If you are going to do some stuff with dates, I recommend using the moment.js library, which will save you from the annoyance that is the Date-object in javascript.

---

Now, from what I understand from your question, you are trying to set the value of the textbox to be the formatted date, which you stored in the variable **ts**.

To set the value of the textbox and also the value of the model, you could simply set the value of **ts** to the model directly, which would then cause Angular to update the value of the textbox.

```
HTML
<div>
  <label for="date">Update Time:</label>
  <input id="date" ng-model="formData.Updt_Time">
</div>


JAVASCRIPT
...
var ts = yr + "-" +mnth+ "-" + dt + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " ";
$scope.formData.Updt_Time = ts;
...
```